# How to find non duplicate <type:keywords> of a file?

Tags: vimscript, command-line, search, external-command

I need a vim shortcut to display all non-duplicate `struct` names in the file being edited. I have made [this C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202598/search-and-print-all-non-duplicate-struct-names-inside-input-file) which does this, however I have to leave the editor and execute the program in `bash` and return back to editing.

Lets say the file being edited is [`linux/drivers/net/ethernet/smsc/smsc911x.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/ethernet/smsc/smsc911x.c?id=965b2aa78fbcb831acf4f669f494da201f4bcace). The output should be like following:

```
 0. smsc911x_data
 1. smsc911x_ops
 2. smsc911x_platform_config
 3. phy_device
 4. mii_bus
 5. net_device
 6. napi_struct
 7. regulator_bulk_data
 8. clk
 9. platform_device
10. sk_buff
11. net_device_stats
12. netdev_hw_addr
13. sockaddr
14. ethtool_drvinfo
15. ethtool_eeprom
16. ethtool_ops
17. net_device_ops
18. resource
19. device_node
20. dev_pm_ops
21. of_device_id
22. platform_driver
```

**EDIT**: The `Parse()` vim routine defined in the answer posted below doesn't prints all the struct names. It's output:

```
0. clk
1. device_node
2. ethtool_drvinfo
3. ethtool_eeprom
4. mii_bus
5. napi_struct
6. net_device
7. netdev_hw_addr
8. phy_device
9. regulator_bulk_data
10. resource
11. sk_buff
12. smsc911x_data
13. smsc911x_platform_config
14. sockaddr
```

I guess its because it is not able to handle cases like `struct { ... } name;`

Comment: Can't you just run `:!./find_structs %`?

Comment: Yes, but i want it to be inside vim so that i can run other operations like jump to struct definition using ctags.

Comment: A plugin like this one might be more convenient: http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/

Comment: @muru: i would prefer a custom vim script than depending on an external plugin especially when you are running vim in an embedded environment.

Comment: Did you try with some search/substitute/sort commands ?

Comment: just use `ctags` and vim tags functionality. "embedded" is no excuse :P  since you can push the source and generate the tags elsewhere, and pull everything back after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:e smsc911x.c
:new
:read !grep -o "struct [^ ;,)]\+" # | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u
```

Explaining:

- `grep -o`: returns only the match chars (useful for multiple match on one line)
- `[^ ;,)]`: remove characters non part of struct name
- `#`: use alternate file (smsc911x.c in this case)

See this gets even more results than your program -once removed that numbered order that I don't know where it comes from-

```
diff --git 1/your_result 2/my_result
index 0bee24a..90d7ce4 100644
--- 1/your_result
+++ 2/my_result
@@ -1,9 +1,13 @@
 clk
+device
 device_node
 dev_pm_ops
+ethtool_cmd
 ethtool_drvinfo
 ethtool_eeprom
 ethtool_ops
+ethtool_regs
+ifreq
 mii_bus
 napi_struct
 netdev_hw_addr
```

Save this to a mapping or function if you feel you will use it from time to time

Answer (score 3):

Here you are :

```
function! Parse()
  " keep only the struct definitions
  v/\v.*(\s|\()struct (\w+).*/d
  " keep only the names of the structs
  %s/\v.*(\s|\()struct (\w+).*/\2/
  " sort and keep non-duplicate lines
  %sort u
  " add line numbers
  %s/^/\=printf('%-d. ', line('.')-1)
endfunction
```

On your file use it with :

```
:call Parse()
```

In the file you provided I didn't match as results as you (but I didn't found any `smsc911x_data` for example).

If you want detailed explanation about how I did just ask :)

Comment: Remove the semicolons from the beginning of the commands,  that is invalid syntax.

Comment: @EvergreenTree No, it's not invalid to have the `:` in vimscript.  Vim just ignores it.  You can have as many leading `:` as you want.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  I always though it designated a one-liner that the user would type out manually.  Interesting!

Comment: I was confused because it worked, but I find it cleaner without

Comment: @Nobe4: Your function displays only 15 out of the 23 struct names shown in the question's example. It missed out the other 9 struct names.

Comment: @manavm-n yes, but as I said, even with a normal search I don't find all keywords. For example : `smsc911x_data`

Comment: Are you using the same file as provided in the link?

Comment: yes, and searching with my browser's finder, I don't find `smsc911x_data`, `smsc911x_ops`, `smsc911x_platform_config` for example ...

Comment: Ahhh.. the person who edited previously put the link to the stable version on Torvald's git tree. However, I posted the output for a prepatch version 4.1.0-rc8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25641/discussion-between-nobe4-and-manav-m-n).

Answer (score 3):

I'd still suggest using the program that you wrote. You can save its output to a scratch buffer and then use tag navigation. Something like (hat-tip to Nobe4):

```
function! Parse()
    let command = "%!/path/to/find_structs " . shellescape(expand('%'))
    new
    " http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ 
    " (How is a scratch (temporary) buffer created?)
    setlocal buftype=nofile
    setlocal bufhidden=hide
    setlocal noswapfile
    set nobuflisted
    execute command
endfunction
```